# Assumptions to be met for a contrast test of mean against zero

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, assumptions, contrasts, lavaan

When doing a contrast test (see `R` code below) or it's rather unusual regression style equivalent, both of which are basically a t-test, what assumptions have to be met? Just the assumptions of a standard t-test?

```
library(multcomp)
# Specifying a contrast comparing the mean to zero
contrast_matrix <- matrix(1, 1, 1)  
contrasttest <- glht(lm(outcome ~ 1, data = data), linfct = contrast_matrix)
summary(contrasttest)

library(lavaan)
contrasttestV2 <- sem('outcome ~ 1', data = data)
summary(contrasttestV2, ci=TRUE)
```

Comment: It's indeed exactly the same set of assumptions for testing that a single parameter is nonzero in linear model using a t-test; indeed there's a way to rewrite your matrix such that your contrast test is equivalent to a regression coefficient test!